# Merge 2 dataFrames with different column name displaying common elements, and differences between dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a script with 2 connections to 2 different databases. I need to compare the results of the queries and show common elements and the differences between the results. 
[image: Data set example]

I have a function which is comparing to dataframes and gives me the differences and common elements, but it gives me an error. I think is because the name of the columns differs in the queries.

```
def compare(a,b):
    if a.equals(b):
       print("SAME!")
    else:
        df = a.merge(b, how='outer',indicator=True)
        x = df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'both', 'm.id']
        y = df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'left_only', 'm.id']
        z = df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'right_only', 'm.id']
        print (f'Display Common Elements contained in Neo4j and MySQL: {", ".join(x)}')
        print (f'Elements found only in Neo4j: {", ".join(y)}')
        print (f'Elements found only in MySQL: {", ".join(z)}')
```

I expect

```
Common elements: C0012345
Elements found only in Neo4j: C027415, C189274
Elements found only in MySQL: C086356, C098876
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a" : ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"b" : ["1","3","2","9","11","23","4"]})

def compare(df1, df2):
    result = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', left_on='a', right_on='b')
    missing_from_a = result.loc[pd.isna(result.a)].b
    missing_from_b = result.loc[pd.isna(result.b)].a
    have_both = result.loc[~pd.isna(result.b)].a.copy()
    have_both.dropna(inplace=True)
    print(", ".join(list(missing_from_b)))
    print(", ".join(list(missing_from_a)))
    print(", ".join(list(have_both)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method beside merge that @Anna Semjen has been described above to find which value is in another dataframe or not:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0 : ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]}) # as MySQL
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"m.id" : ["1","3","2","9","11","23","4"]}) # as Neo4j
print('Elements found only in MySQL: '+ ','.join(list(df1[~df1[0].isin(df2['m.id'])].iloc[:,0].tolist())))
print('Elements found only in Neo4j: '+ ','.join(list(df2[~(df2['m.id'].isin(df1[0]))].iloc[:,0].tolist())))
print('Elements found in both Neo4j & MySQL: '+ ','.join(df1[df1[0].isin(df2['m.id'])].iloc[:,0].tolist()))
```

Output:

```
Elements found only in MySQL: 5,6,7
Elements found only in Neo4j: 9,11,23
Elements found in both Neo4j & MySQL: 1,2,3,4
```

Hope this help you as a reference of another method :)

Answer (score 0):

## Update for pandas 1.1.0+

#### Pandas has included a [`pd.DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html#pandas.DataFrame.compare) method:

We can compare dataframes with the same indexing like this:

```
df1.compare(df2.rename(columns={'b':'a'}))
```

Output:

```
     a      
  self other
1    2     3
2    3     2
3    4     9
4    5    11
5    6    23
6    7     4
```

#### Or we can use [`pd.Series.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.compare.html#pandas.Series.compare) like this:

```
df1['a'].compare(df2['b'])
```

Output:

```
  self other
1    2     3
2    3     2
3    4     9
4    5    11
5    6    23
6    7     4
```